# Is there a way to choose order for detox tests?

Tags: detox

I created multiple test files like this:

```
0_setup.e2e.js
1_otherTests.e2e.js
2_loggedInTests.e2e.js
```

But it executed it out of order. It executed in this order:

```
0_setup.e2e.js
2_loggedInTests.e2e.js
1_otherTests.e2e.js
```

Comment: It is possible to do so: use customSequencer in jest.config  
https://jestjs.io/docs/29.5/configuration#testsequencer-string  
don't forget to `npm i -D @jest/test-sequencer`   
And pay attention to the rootDir in your jest.config, my path looked like this:     `testSequencer: '<rootDir>/e2e/customSequencer.js',`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is probably not. A more elaborate answer us that it is test runner dependent. But you should not be creating any dependencies or order requirements between test suites; thats a bad practice in general.